# Decode ASP Request.ClientCertificate("Certificate") from a .NET COM library

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, ssl, x509certificate2

In an effort to further refine my question this is the 3rd rewrite. Here is the scenario in a nutshell.

1. Legacy ASP / VBscript website
2. .NET / C# COM library which is used in the ASP site
3. I want to send the Request.ClientCertificate("Certificate") in it's raw form to my .NET COM library and decode it so I can validate fields against the client certificate in Active Directory.

   - The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524668%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for Request.ClientCertificate("Certificate") says that it's a string of the binary data that represents the certificate in ASN.1 format. My .NET method that receives this has a string type for the parameter. I've tried using **Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes**, **Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes** and **Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes** to convert it to a byte[] that the **X509Certificate2** constructor expects.

I have tried searching Google for every shred of information I can find on how to do something useful (ie. decode) the ASP Request.ClientCertificate in it's raw form but have come up empty. I've also saved this data to a file and attempted to decode this using CertUtil but it still fails to decode the data and just errors out.

As I continue to play around with this I decided to look at the size of the client certificate returned by ASP and ASP.NET and I found the size to not match. My certificate coming from ASP was 647 bytes and 1295 bytes in ASP.NET. I don't know why the size is skewed between both environments. Consequently I have no issues whatsoever decoding the client certificate returned by ASP.NET using the X509Certicate2 class.

I've also tried using the following p/invoked function:

```
[DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint CertCreateCertificateContext(uint dwCertEncodingType, 
  byte[] pbCertEncoded, uint cbCertEncoded);
```

So in either case of using X509Certificate, X509Certificate2 and the function above I get a consistent result the certificate coming from ASP is not usable by these functions. The X509Certificate class just throws an exception when I try to construct it with the byte[] representing the certificate.

I've tried using the CAPICOM library to import the certificate but I get exactly the same exception that the X509Certificate2 class gives me.

*Cannot find the requested object*

**So in summary what I want to do is, decode the ASP Request.ClientCertificate("Certificate") from a .NET / C# COM library utilizing the X509Certificate set of classes.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue and it is very simple. I had to base 64 encode the Request.ClientCertificate("Certificate") using the CAPICOM Utilities class on the ASP side. Once I did that, called my .NET COM method with an ASCII conversion to byte[] and the X509Certificate2 class had no trouble with decoding the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem has to do with marshaling of the certificate data when it is transmitted through the COM interface that you have created. Notice that the ASP certificate size (647) is almost exactly half of the .NET certificate size (1295). Are you perhaps inadvertently converting an array of 8 bit bytes on the ASP side to a 16 bit Unicode string? It would help to see the interface definition of the COM server that you have created to decode the certificate.

Comment: Those sizes are of the client certificate within each environment, ie. no passing data back and forth, two separate apps I created just to see what the certificates looked like in the two environments ie. ASP and ASP.NET. So the sizes are in fact being reported differently in both environments. I'm using Request.ClientCertificate("Certificate") in ASP and Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate in ASP.NET.

Comment: Your certificate decoding works in the .NET environment, and the format of Request.ClientCertificate("Certificate") is the same on both platforms. That leaves only 2 possibilities: either the classic ASP environment is not giving you a valid certificate or you aren't transferring the data properly between environments. I would focus on the latter case. Keep in mind that the return from the ASP collection will be of type variant, and silent type conversions are possible. Make sure you are properly converting the ASP type to System.Byte[] so that is can be consumed by your .NET code.

Comment: The return type of Request.ClientCertificate("Certificate") is string containing the binary data of the certificate according to the documentation. I am passing this to a .NET method which takes a string. I convert it into a byte[] on the .NET side which is probably where the problem is occurring. I've tried converting it using Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes and I've also tried ASCII.

Comment: It sounds like you are very close to a solution. My recommendation is to perform a byte-by-byte comparison of the first 16-32 bytes for both the working ASP.NET certificate data and the broken ASP data from the same client certificate. That will give you an idea of how to perform an accurate conversion. You may be able to provide a workaround; you might also try changing the parameter of your COM interface to byte[]. I suspect the actual type returned from Request.ClientCertificate("Certificate") is a SAFEARRAY of Bytes, and if you pass a byte[] parameter you might avoid a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this page](http://ntserver.slctech.org/iishelp/iis/htm/core/iicrtsc.htm) it seems it's possible to take the certificate and put it into base64 encoded X509. If you pass that string to the .NET side, you can create a byte array from it and then use the [X509Certificate2 constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148413%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to create an instance of the certificate.

You'd probably be better off though using the [properties of the certificate class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524668%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in ASP to extract the information you want and then pass that on.

Comment: Yeah I found this code in a number of different places and tried it but it still will not decode with the X509Certificate2 class.

Comment: Apparently I'm not doing something correctly. I am able to decode client certificates contained in Active Directory accounts with the X509Certificate2 class no problem. The problem is going from ASP to my .NET COM lib trying to pass the client certificate from ASP.

Comment: Utilizing the already decoded fields contained in the ASP Request.ClientCertificate collection is my last resort. I was hoping to just send the raw certificate to my .NET code and perform the decode and validation there.

Comment: Strange - if that code encodes right it should work. You could try using certutil -dump (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443%28WS.10%29.aspx) to see if it's in the correct format.

Comment: I couldn't get CertUtil to do anything useful with the certificate saved via that code. It appears as though the part that encodes the data is not doing it correctly. If I view the file in a text editor the part between BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE is mostly the same characters repeated over and over.

Comment: Yea, sounds that way. Sorry it was a bust.